# count query with group by but exclude users

Tags: sql

I have made a sql query:

```
select Count (UserId) 
from PlanData 
where AirlineCode='cl' 
  and DateStart>'2019-07-01' 
  and DateEnd<'2019-07-31' 
group by UserId
```

This will give me false results because actually I would like to exclude `UserId`s completely from the query which have `GeneralEventCode='code1','code2'` in it

Comment: `and GeneralEventCode  not in ('code1', 'code2')`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, That must be posted as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not that's not the solution. then this codes wouldn't be included in the counting. But I would like that I get a result where when 'code1' and 'code2' is in it would be excluded totally, thus this UserIds would not show up at all in the result

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How can you exclude the codes and include it in the count at the same time. Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: July 2 to 30? Seems a bit odd to skip a month's first and last day.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hope now it is more clear?

Comment: Are those codes applied over *all* times or just during the specified time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I think that you need a `HAVING` clause and not a `WHERE` clause:

```
select Count(UserId) 
from PlanData 
where AirlineCode='cl' 
  and DateStart>'2019-07-01' 
  and DateEnd<'2019-07-31' 
group by UserId
having Count(case when GeneralEventCode in ('code1', 'code2') then 1 end) = 0
```

This conditional `COUNT()` in the `HAVING` clause will filter out any user with any occurrence of `'code1'` or `'code2'` in the column `GeneralEventCode`.  
Also recheck your condition about the dates, maybe you need `>=` and `<=`.